Got "PydanticUserError" when import ChatGroq
I have following packages installed
langchain_core==0.2.39
langchain==0.2.16
langchain-community==0.2.16
langchain_groq==0.1.10
langchain_openai==0.1.24
fastapi==0.114.2
redis
pyyaml

However, when I try to
from langchain_groq import ChatGroq

I got error
PydanticUserError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[20], line 70
     64 #print(pm)
     65 
     66 
     68 import os
---> 70 from langchain_groq import ChatGroq

File /opt/anaconda3/envs/my_env/lib/python3.12/site-packages/langchain_groq/__init__.py:1
----> 1 from langchain_groq.chat_models import ChatGroq
      3 __all__ = ["ChatGroq"]

File /opt/anaconda3/envs/my_env/lib/python3.12/site-packages/langchain_groq/chat_models.py:87
     80 from langchain_core.utils.function_calling import (
     81     convert_to_openai_function,
     82     convert_to_openai_tool,
     83 )
     84 from langchain_core.utils.pydantic import is_basemodel_subclass
---> 87 class ChatGroq(BaseChatModel):
     88     """`Groq` Chat large language models API.
     89 
     90     To use, you should have the
   (...)
    296             'logprobs': None}
...
   2454 if hasattr(tp, '__origin__') and not is_annotated(tp):

PydanticUserError: The `__modify_schema__` method is not supported in Pydantic v2. Use `__get_pydantic_json_schema__` instead in class `SecretStr`.

For further information visit https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.9/u/custom-json-schema

Please advise.

The issue was caused by fastapi version. Sorry, I haven't put the whole code out. But it clearly the fastapi version doesn't support Pydantic v2, which cause the issue when try to import Groq. So after upgrade to fastapi 0.115.0, everything works fine.

This could be because of older versions of langchain and it's related libraries using pydantic v1. To resolve this, you can uninstall all related packages with the help of pip list,I uninstalled almost all packages and installed again.
https://python.langchain.com/v0.2/docs/how_to/pydantic_compatibility/
